# "TYPEOF" equivalent in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am curios to know if there an Mysql operator/function which says the type of a value. Say, I would like to print the type of value of a (manipulated)column returned from a sub-query.

Comment: You can't get type of "value" entered but you can get type of "column" of that field. You want that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get type of "value" entered but you can get type of "column" of that field as below code shows:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM tableName where Field ='nameOfField;'
```